# What conjugation is `repart` for `repartir`?

Tags: conjugaison

[Today's page of www.VerbeDuJour.com](http://www.verbedujour.com) for the verb `repartir` shows this example text:

> Samuel repart dans la rue acheter du pain.

Two questions about conjugations.

- None of the ten conjugations (PRÉSENT, FUTUR, etc.) displayed on that page are as short as the six-letter `depart`. All the conjugations continue with `reparti…` such as `il répartit` and `il répartira`. So what conjugation is `depart`?
- Should `repart` have an accent `répart` as do all the conjunctions listed on that page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That website is wrong. It is giving you the conjugations for the verb *répartir* (to divide), not *repartir* (to restart).

You can see the correct conjugations in any good online dictionary. ([Here's a link to the correct page on WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/FrVerbs.aspx?v=repartir).)

To answer your question, *repart* is present tense and should not have an accent. The core root of this particular verb is "*repar*-" and that will not change no matter the verb tense; only the ending will vary.